# I’m stuck on some LINQ to XML code (<![CDATA[ ]] &gt;)

Tags: .net, xml, linq, cdata

I’m stuck on some LINQ to XML code.  A method is called in a for loop that successfully returns the contents of a `<placemark>` tag containing the correct `<placemark>` id from a kml file that has 4000+ `<placemark>`’s total.  I say successfully with one caveat.  The `<description>` tag contains `<![CDATA[ ]]>` that .net translates into `<![CDATA[ ]] &gt;` .  I can’t figure out anyway of getting this parsed so that it preserves all of the characters (the `>`).  Here is the relevant c# code:

…in main class

```
public partial class ResultsGeneral : BasePage {
public List<string> rightVenues = new List<string>();
XNamespace spc = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";
XDocument Placemarks = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/venuesCompleteGood.kml"));
```

…in `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {`

```
for (int q = 0; q <= rightVenues.Count; q++) {
    getInfo(rightVenues[q]); //get info contains a list of placemark ids
};
```

…

```
public void getInfo(string ids) {
    var aPlacemark =
    from plMark in Placemarks.Descendants(spc + "Placemark")
        where plMark.Attribute("id").Value.Equals(ids.ToString())
        select plMark;
    foreach (XElement plMark in aPlacemark) {
        quKML.Text = quKML.Text + "<br>" + 
               plMark.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
    }
}
```

…a snippet of the kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
        <Document>
            <Placemark id="33">
               <name>
                    Madison Square Garden
               </name>
               <description>
                    <![CDATA[<br>
4 Penn Plaza<br>
<br>
New York<br>
NY<br>
10001<br>
United States of America ]]>
               </description>
               <Point>
                    <coordinates>
                         -73.99337100000002,40.750354
                    </coordinates>
               </Point>
          </Placemark>
```

…part of what is returned:

```
<placemark id="33" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><name>
                    Madison Square Garden
               </name><description><!--[CDATA[<br-->
4 Penn Plaza<br>
<br>
New York<br>
NY<br>
10001<br>
United States of America ]]&gt;</description><point><coordinates>
                         -73.99337100000002,40.750354
                    </coordinates></point></placemark>
```

note the `]]&gt;` after America.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your getInfo method, it looks like plMark.ToString(...) is returning the right text, so I would be investigating quKML, I might be missing something, but I can't see what data type this is?

In addition, if quKML is supposed to be XML based, I'd think about altering your `<br>` to a self closing tag `<br/>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: quKML is a asp label to display the output to the webpage.  quKML is a string

Comment: Which .Net framework are you targeting? I wasn't able to reproduce in a Windows Forms test host app that was targeting the 4.0 framework using this code :-(

Comment: Using 4.0, it's a web project

Comment: well, it's not quKML.Text, 
just assigned 'kmlStuff = kmlStuff + "<br>" + plMark.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);' to a string var and then used <%=kmlStuff %> to display it. and got the same &gt; results